# Offline folders says there is not enough free space on the drive - but there is (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, offline-files

I have been using Windows Offline Folders for some years now, without too much hair torn out. 
However, after reinstalling Windows and setting up my tried-out configuration, synchronization stops abruptly with a "There is not enough free space on the drive" message. (Or something like that... my Windows 7 does not speak English).

The configuration of the system:

- Windows 7 Professional
- CSC folder moved to another partition than the default
- Offline Folders allowed to use 255 GB of space, of which it uses 5.95 GB
- Target drive has 64.5 GB free (excluding current CSC)
- Total size of folder to cache is approx. 25 GB

Comment: How much free space is available on the partition where Windows is?  Many Microsoft utilities (stupidly) use the C: drive as temp space, even when you specify that the target is somewhere else.

Comment: There is more than enough space. Also, the Offline folders settings confirms, that there is more free space available for a local copy than required.
I still haven't been able to figure out this problem. 
However, I see that it always hangs while syncing files with names starting with a '$' sign.